# Upload image and video in form and store data in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, forms, upload

I've tried to make a form for uploading pictures and videos and renaming them with a specific id from mysql.

The data is stored in mysql, the picture is uploading but video is not uploaded. Could somebody tell me where is wrong?

form code:

```
<form id='adaugaanunt' name='add-item' method='post' action='add_in_video.php'     enctype='multipart/form-data' onsubmit="return jcap();">
<div class='container'>
<label for='titlu' >*Titlu:</label><br />
<input name='titlu' required='required' placeholder='ex. Vand ceas ROLEX' type='text'  class='input required' /></div><br />
<div class='container'>
<label for='descriere' >*Descriere:</label><br />
<input name='descriere' required='required' placeholder='ex. Vand ceas ROLEX cu luminite' type='text' class='input required' /></div><br />
<div class='container'>
<label for='pic1' >Poza: </label><br />
<input name='pic1' type='file' /><br />
</div><br />
<div class='container'>
<label for='vid1' >Video: </label><br />
<input name='vid1' type='file' /><br />
</div><br />
<div class='container' style="float:right"><input name='submit' type='submit' value='Trimite' /></div>
<div class='container' style="float:left"><input type="reset" name="Reseteaza" value="Reseteaza"></div>
</form>
```

add_in_video.php

```
<?php include 'include/global.php'; 
$titlu = str_replace("'","`",$_POST['titlu']);
$cere = "SELECT * FROM `video` WHERE titlu='".$titlu."'";
$rez = mysql_query($cere);
$cnt = mysql_num_rows($rez);
if ($cnt == 0) {
$title = htmlentities($titlu);
$descriere = htmlentities($_POST['descriere']);
$cerereSQL = "INSERT INTO `video` (`id` , `titlu`, `descriere`)
VALUES ('', '$titlu', '$descriere')";
//echo $cerereSQL;
$result_insert_user = mysql_query($cerereSQL);
if (file_exists("../videos/".mysql_insert_id()."a.jpg"))
{
unlink("../videos/".mysql_insert_id()."a.jpg");
}
if (file_exists("../videos/".mysql_insert_id()."b.avi"))
{
unlink("../videos/".mysql_insert_id()."b.avi");
}
if ($_FILES["pic1"]["name"] != "") {
if (($_FILES["pic1"]["type"] == "image/gif") || ($_FILES["pic1"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") || ($_FILES["pic1"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg") || ($_FILES["pic1"]["type"] == "image/bmp"))
{
if ($_FILES["pic1"]["error"] > 0)
{
echo "A intervenit o eroare: " . $_FILES["pic1"]["error"] . "<br />";
}
else
{
if (file_exists("../videos/" . $_FILES["pic1"]["tmp_name"]))
  {
  echo "Poza exista deja";
  }
 else
  {
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["pic1"]["tmp_name"], "../videos/".mysql_insert_id()."a.jpg");
  }
 }
 }
else
{
header('Location: '.$domain.'index.php');
exit;
}
}

if ($_FILES["vid1"]["name"] != "") {
$allowedExts = array("wmv","avi","mpeg","mpg", "mp4");
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["vid1"]["name"]));
if ((($_FILES["vid1"]["type"] == "video/mp4") || ($_FILES["vid1"]["type"] == "video/wmv") || ($_FILES["vid1"]["type"] == "video/mpg") || ($_FILES["vid1"]["type"] == "video/mpeg")) && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
 {
if ($_FILES["vid1"]["error"] > 0)
{
echo "A intervenit o eroare: " . $_FILES["vid1"]["error"] . "<br />";
}
else
{
if (file_exists("../videos/" . $_FILES["vid1"]["tmp_name"]))
  {
  echo "Acest video exista deja";
  }
else
  {
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["vid1"]["tmp_name"], "../videos/".mysql_insert_id()."b.avi");
    }
   }
 }
else
{
header('Location: '.$domain.'index.php');
exit;
}
}



} else {
header('Location: '.$domain.'index.php');
exit;
}
?>
```

I don`t recieve any error message. The image file is uploading and the video file is NOT UPLOADING.
Sorry about this code, I`m new to PHP/MYSQL.
I need to store that files local, because I have a videoplayer that is populated from that folder.

Comment: that's a lot of poorly formatted code you expect us to try debug, you need to narrow this down for us

Comment: Are you getting to the error line "A intervenit o eroare: " . $_FILES["pic1"]["error"]" or is the file just not being uploaded?

Comment: Why store the actual image/video in mysql? It is much more efficient to store it in something like a CDN or Amazon S3.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that the error code is in fact zero (it's the first reason the file isn't there). If it is not zero then you can find information on the error codes [PHP - Error Messages Explained](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php)

You should check the return value of move_uploaded_file:

```
$tmp_name = $_FILES["vid1"]["tmp_name"];
$name = "../videos/" . mysql_insert_id() . "b.avi";
if(!move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $name)){
    print "Could not move file $tmp_name to $name<br>";
} else {
    print "Successfully copied files<br>";
}
```

Chances are there was an error in the move_uploaded_file call and subsequent warnings were suppressed by PHP

You can print all errors/warnings/messages by calling `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the beginning of your script. More info on error reporting here - [PHP - error_reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)